# Keep getting "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" while trying to manipulate strings in panda dataframe

Tags: pandas, typeerror

I am attempting to use code that has worked in the past to cycle through a column in a dataframe, count the number of occurrences of a list of words, and set those values to a new column.

Essentially, I have a column of text where I want a count of the number of times "cough|hack|etc." appears in each cell in the column. Unfortunately, when I run that code I get :

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I think it's an issue with the `dtypes`, as they are all objects.

However,

1. I'm working with strings, so I though object was fine, and
2. when I try to change `dtypes to int32` for the numerical variables, I get the same error. I also go the same error when attempting to concatenate text in two columns. I think there's just something silly I'm overlooking, but I could use some help.

```
data=pd.read_csv("C:/path.csv", header = None, low_memory = False, sep = ",") #loading in my data 
col_names = data.loc[0,:].values.tolist()
data.columns=[col_names]

def get_counts(text):               #function to get counts
    return len(re.findall(r"(term1|term2|termX)", text.lower()))

data['X_count']=data.text_variable.apply(lambda x: get_narrow_counts(x))  #apply function to each cell in column
```

All `.astype()` approaches to converting to a different dtype lead to the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks invalid,  the function you def and function you call from lambda are different

From my understanding of your requirement this works

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["term1, term2, termX"],["some text termX"]], columns=["text_variable"])
df["X_count"] = df.text_variable.str.findall(r"(term1|term2|termX)").apply(lambda r: len(r))
df
```

**output**

```
    text_variable   X_count
0   term1, term2, termX 3
1   some text termX 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I don't think invalid code is the issue. I've used this code a dozen times or so, and it still works on another .csv file in another .ipynb notebook, but for some reason won't run on this new .csv file. I'm assuming it's something to do with all my dtypes being objects, but any code to change dyptes comes back with the same error above.

Comment: without actual code and data cannot tell what from question the issue.   paste in data from df causing your issues and I can help `def get_counts(text):` and `lambda x: get_narrow_counts(x)` cannot work together